# Convert SQL to SQL alchemy

Tags: python, mysql, orm, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I am new to Flask SQl alchemy; Though i understand that alchemy abstracts the sql syntax and makes things easy while creating models; there could be times when we want to visualize data in the front end in a very specific way.

I have the following query which i would like to use using alchemy using session.query and filter and possibly grouping.

My query reads:

1. mysql> `SELECT status, COUNT(id) FROM bar_baz where not name = 'Foo' and not name = 'Bar' GROUP BY status`
2. `select (select COUNT(id) FROM instance where not name = 'erf' and not tiername = 'wer' and type='app') as app, (select COUNT(1) FROM instance_2 where not name = 'visq' and not name = 'werf' and type='adc') as adc from dual;`

I verified that the following queries works with the MySQL; I was wondering if we have a function similar to

```
c = conn.cursor()
query = 'SELECT status, COUNT(id) FROM bar_baz where not name = 'Foo' and not name = 'Bar' GROUP BY status'
c.execute(query)
print c.fetchall()


class Instance(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'instance'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)
    status = Column(String)
    type = Column(String)

class Instance2(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'instance_2'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)
    status = Column(String)
    type = Column(String)
    inc = Column(Integer)
```

The query of Interest:

```
select (select COUNT(id) FROM instance where not name = 'erf' and not tiername = 'wer' and type='app') as app, (select COUNT(1) FROM instance_2 where not name = 'visq' and not name = 'werf' and type='adc') as adc from dual;`
```

Comment: You *can just do that*; pass a raw query to the connection. You'll get result rows back. It'll be more more powerful and secure if you use SQLAlchemy to generate the query instead though.

Comment: I decided not to pass sql query to connection; I would be more interested in using alchemy using session.query and filters

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the first query, use `db.func.count` to produce the count expression.  Everything else should be obvious from the [docs](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/query.html).

```
status_counts = db.session.query(BarBaz.status, db.func.count(BarBaz.id).label('count_id')
).filter(db.not_(db.or_(BarBaz.name == 'Foo', BarBaz.name == 'Bar'))
).group_by(BarBaz.status
).all()
```

For the second query, use [`subquery()`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/query.html?highlight=subquery#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.subquery) to produce selectable queries.

```
sub_app = db.session.query(db.func.count(Instance.id).label('app')
).filter(db.not_(db.or_(Instance.name == 'erf', Instance.tiername == 'wer')), Instance.type == 'app'
).subquery()

sub_adc = db.session.query(db.func.count(Instance.id).label('adc')
).filter(db.not_(db.or_(Instance2.name == 'visq', Instance2.name == 'werf')), Instance2.type == 'adc'
).subquery()

out = db.session.query(sub_app.c.app, sub_adc.c.adc).all()
```