# Convert SQL to sqlalchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm looking to convert my raw sql to sqlalchemy but do not know if i need to do join or not.

My query is to select certain columns from certain tables and join them based on the foreign key of user.id. One user can have multiple favorites.

The query I came up with is as follows but, I'm not sure how to do this in sqlalchemy. I can achieve a similar result with the following raw sql.

```
SELECT favorite.id AS favorite_id, favorite.name AS favorite_name, user.id AS user_id, user.display_name AS user_display_name FROM favorite, user WHERE favorite.user_id = user.id AND user.is_active = 't''
```

Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24508070/convert-sql-to-sql-alchemy any use?

Comment: yes thanks @TheGeorgeL

Comment: That's why I always say that it's worth searching stackoverflow before asking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
favorites = db.session.query(
    # OR you could specifically get columns by Favorite.id,
    Favorite
    User,
).filter(
    Favorite.user_id==user.id,
).all()
```