# convert sql to sqlalchemy with alias using selectable subquery

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I want to find the couple of : each zone with all the stores from my table `store` where the associated zone is closed to the zone.
The following sql request works well:

```
SELECT zone_1.id AS zone_1_id, store_1.id AS store_1_id
FROM zone as zone_1 JOIN store store_1 on store_1.zone_id != zone_1.id
WHERE ST_DWithin(zone_1.point, (SELECT zone2.point AS zone_point 
FROM zone as zone2
WHERE zone2.id = store_1.zone_id), 10)
```

But when i convert it in sqlalchemy, something failed:

```
z1 = aliased(zone)
z2 = aliased(zone)
s1 = aliased(store)
close_store_query = z1.query(z1.id,s1.id).join(s1, z1.id != s1.zone_id ).filter(
    func.ST_DWithin(z1.point, z2.query(z2.point).filter(z2.id == s1.zone_id), 10),
)
```

i got the following error :

```
sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.errors.SyntaxError) subquery in FROM must have an alias
```

do you have any idea of why he don't work , i'm not sure if i need to use selectable subquery.

The command generated by sqlalchemy is :

```
SELECT zone_1.id AS zone_1_id, store_1.id AS store_1_id
FROM (SELECT zone_2.point AS zone_2_point 
FROM zone AS zone_2, store AS store_1 
WHERE zone_2.id = store_1.zone_id), zone AS zone_1 JOIN store AS store_1 ON zone_1.id != store_1.zone_id 
WHERE ST_DWithin(zone_1.point, (SELECT zone_2.point AS zone_2_point 
FROM zone AS zone_2 
WHERE zone_2.id = store_1.zone_id), :ST_DWithin_1)
```

the first FROM should not be there ..

Comment: What's your conversion method? I believe you would have to use `subquery` to produce selectable queries. see [this for an example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24513072/6505847)

Comment: I convert it by myself i don't use any tools, do you recommand one ?

Comment: That's what seems like a good option