# Confusing SQLAlchemy conversion of simple subquery

Tags: python, mysql, sql, sqlalchemy

I've been wrestling with what should be a simple conversion of a straightforward SQL query into an SQLAlchemy expression, and I just cannot get things to line up the way I mean in the subquery. This is a single-table query of a "Comments" table; I want to find which users have made the most first comments:

```
SELECT user_id, count(*) AS count
FROM comments c
where c.date = (SELECT MIN(c2.date)
                FROM comments c2 
                WHERE c2.post_id = c.post_id
               )
GROUP BY user_id
ORDER BY count DESC
LIMIT 20;
```

I don't know how to write the subquery so that it refers to the outer query, and if I did, I wouldn't know how to assemble this into the outer query itself. (Using MySQL, which shouldn't matter.)

Comment: I'm not sure if this could help but try [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24508070/convert-sql-to-sql-alchemy) or [this official docs](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/query.html?highlight=subquery#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.subquery).

Answer (score 1):

Well, after giving up for a while and then looking back at it, I came up with something that works. I'm sure there's a better way, but:

```
 c2 = aliased(Comment)
 firstdate = select([func.min(c2.date)]).\
       where(c2.post_id == Comment.post_id).\
       as_scalar()  # or scalar_subquery(), in SQLA 1.4

 users = session.query(
    Comment.user_id, func.count('*').label('count')).\
        filter(Comment.date == firstdate).\
        group_by(Comment.user_id).\
        order_by(desc('count')).\
        limit(20)
```